# How to obtain the daily Temporal variation chart using Sentinel 5p methane

Tags: google-earth-engine, time, sentinel, sentinel-5p

I want to generate the daily temporal variation chart of methane concentration over India for the years 2019, 2020, 2021 and 2022. The average methane values for a single day, say, 1st January  is to be calculated by taking the average of methane values on 1-1-2019, 1-1-2020, 1-1-2021 and 1-1-2022.

How can I achieve this?

I used GEE to obtain the 60th percentile methane values for a year using the following code.

What changes should I make in this code to get the preferred result?

Code:

```
var ROI = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','IN'))

var CH4bands = CH4.select('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air')

var image = CH4bands.filterBounds(ROI)

var CH4filterdate = image.filterDate('2019-02-08','2019-12-31')
print('Number of images: ', CH4filterdate.size())

var band_viz = {
  min: 1750,
  max: 1900,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

print(ROI.geometry().coordinates().flatten().size())

var percentileCH4 = CH4filterdate.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([60]));
Map.addLayer(percentileCH4.clip(ROI), band_viz, 'CH4 India')


var scale = 20000
print(ROI.geometry().simplify(scale).coordinates().flatten().size())

ROI = ROI.geometry().simplify(scale)
Map.addLayer(ROI, {}, 'ROI')
Map.centerObject(ROI, 5)

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(CH4filterdate, ROI, ee.Reducer.percentile([60]), scale, 'system:time_start')
.setOptions({
   lineWidth: 1,
   title: 'CH4 Concentration',
   interpolateNulls: true,
   vAxis: {title: 'Concentration(ppb)'},
   hAxis: {title: 'Month', format: 'MMM'}
})

print (chart)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to chart the mean value across these 4 years and across the AOI for each day of the year? I'm a bit confused because of your chart label `Month`. Try something like the below. It's a lot of data to crunch, so it takes time to generate the chart.

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_CH4')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .select('CH4_column_volume_mixing_ratio_dry_air')
var dayOfYearCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(1, 365) // Let's just ignore the leap day
  .map(function(dayOfYear) {
    dayOfYear = ee.Number(dayOfYear)
    return collection
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(dayOfYear, dayOfYear, 'day_of_year'))
      .mean()
      .set('dayOfYear', dayOfYear)
  })
)
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: dayOfYearCollection,
  region: aoi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 20000,
  xProperty: 'dayOfYear'
})
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a95748e0141e324f32851eec8cad66e4

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I want the mean value on a single day, say, January 1 of every year from 2019 to 2022. Is it possible to get the value for a single day by taking mean of values on Jan 1 of every year?

Comment: That’s exactly what the script is doing. Mean of Jan 1, mean of Jan 2, …, mean of dec 31. 365 means, one for each day of the year.

Comment: YES, I understand. But I want to calculate the value for Jan 1 only, not everyday of the year. Also not for a single year, but the average of sum of values on Jan 1 of every year